# How to refer to a variable via a string containing its name?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to classify the projects by searching keywords. For each category of project type, I have an array of key words. I will use the variable name as the project type and the contents of the variable as keywords for matching.

```
project_detail = "Build a school"
a   = %w[education school]
b       = ["Health Care", "Clean Water"]
projects    = %w[a b]
project_type = String.new
projects.each do |e|
   # How to refer to the variable a and b? (I used one of the answers)
   eval(e).each do |keyword|        
       project_type = e if project_detail.match(/#{keyword}/)
   end  
end
```

Comment: I suggest you read about basics of ruby

Comment: **You do not want to refer to local variables from inside iteration.** And if you do, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Why not `vars = [a, b, c]`? Do you _need_ access by name? I don't think so.

Comment: This is most likely an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thanks for the link to XY problem. I am learning how to ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I will use the variable name as the project type ...

Don't use variable names to represent data. Variables should refer to data, not be that data. Here's how I would approach it.

First of all, I would create a small [class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Classes) for project types. The class should have two attributes, `name` and `keywords`. This can be done using the `class` keyword:

```
class ProjectType
  attr_accessor :name, :keywords

  def initialize(name, keywords)
    @name = name
    @keywords = keywords
  end
end
```

or via [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Struct.html):

```
ProjectType = Struct.new(:name, :keywords)
```

Then, I would create an array of all project types:

```
@project_types = [
  ProjectType.new('a', %w[education school]),
  ProjectType.new('b', ['Health Care', 'Clean Water'])
]
```

Now, we need a way to find a project by keyword. I would wrap that in a method:

```
def find_project_type(name)
  @project_types.find do |prj|
    Regexp.union(prj.keywords) =~ name
  end
end
```

[`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) traverses the `@project_types` array, returning the first element for which the block returns `true`. Within the block, we use [`Regexp.union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) to build a regexp matching all of the project's keywords and [`=~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D~) to perform the match.

The method can now be used like this:

```
project_type = find_project_type("Build a school")
#=> #<struct ProjectType name="a", keywords=["education", "school"]>
```

The project type's name can be retrieved via:

```
project_type.name
#=> "a"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and detailed explanation.

Comment: Some projects can be classified into multiple types. For example, "Building a school for girls" can be classified as "education" and "women empowerment". How can I modify the code to deal with this situation?

Comment: @JXU just use `select` instead of `find` – it returns all matching items, not just the first one.

Answer (score 2):

You could use any of the below:

#### 1. eval

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
vars = %w[a b c]
vars.each { |v| puts eval(v) }
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
 => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

#### 2. Binding#local_variable_get

```
vars.each { |v| puts binding.local_variable_get(v) }
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. I edited the question to incorporate your answer. I also gave a bit more detail about why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that you want to use the variable *e* to get to the contents of, say, a.

In this case, you could use `eval(e)`, because *e* is of class *String*.

Of course the question is why you want to access a variable via a string holding its name .....

Comment: I edited the question and explained why I want to access a variable via a string.

Comment: Your edit doesn't explain why you need to access the variable via a string. Why can't you simply use a data structure mapping the project type to the keywords? Why do you have to use metaprogramming for such a simple task?